# How to get permission result from activity in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-fragmentactivity

I have `MapFragment` and I check for permission at `onViewCreated`:

```
  if (uiCommunicationListener.isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
        permission_button.visibility = View.GONE
        val mapFragment =
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
    } else {
        //Hide Map
    }
```

`uiCommunicationListener` is an interface that responsible for fragments-activity communication.

`isLocationPermissionGranted` located in `MainActivity` and looks like this:

```
override fun isLocationPermissionGranted(): Boolean {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //  Ask for permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            Constants.LOCATION_PREMMISION_CODE
        )
        return false
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
        return true
    }
```

Basically it is checking if permission is granted, if it is return true, if it's not ask for permission and return false.

The problem is that I can't do operation based on user action after we ask him for permissions.

In my case I'm checking if permission has been granted, if it is show the map if it's not hide the map.

But if it return false, and after the request permission dialog pops up and the user grant us permission, nothing happen because we already "Passed" the if check

Now Usually in `onRequestPermissionsResult` method I can make operation based on user actions(Grant us permssion/Deny the request) but here this method lives inside MainActivity and I can't get access to the request code, grant result etc.

How can I make operations in the fragment based on the result of request permission dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have `onRequestPermissionsResult` in Fragment as well.
2. If you still want to have `onRequestPermissionsResult` centrally in your `Activity`, you need to call the method of `Fragment` `onRequestPermissionsResult` of your `Activity`

   ```
   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERM: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, do your work....

                    YourFragmentClass fragment = 
                    (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
                    fragment.yourPublicMethod();

                } else {
                    // permission denied
                    // Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' statements for other permssions
        }
    }
   ```

Note : There are other ways as well to interact with `Fragment` from `Activity`.

Comment: this method is deprecated for fragment

Answer (score 1):

Fragment class has `requestPermissions` and `onRequestPermissionsResult` methods/functions itself. You can use that for your reason.

[Fragment.requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#requestpermissions)

[Fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D))

Comment: Actually I tried to request premissions in ```MainActivity``` and use ```onRequestPermissionsResult ``` in the fragment but it doens't seem to do anything.  I know I can easily request and get the permissions inside the fragment, but didn't permission handling  should be i a global place?

Comment: No it's not necessary and better to say, it shouldn't be global. If you need permission in one place, it's better to request and handle that inside that specific place itself.

Comment: If you like to manage that globally inside your activity, then you should define a public method inside your fragment to do post-permission-request actions and then call it inside your activity after permission is granted. It would be a better approach to define and use an interface inside your fragment to handle this and implement that listener inside your activity.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void showContacts() {
     if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                 PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
     } else {
         doShowContacts();
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
         int[] grantResults) {
     if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS
             && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         doShowContacts();
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is you question or issue here?